# Error rendering react app to static site using webpack: ReferenceError: document is not defined

Tags: reactjs, webpack

So I am attempting to use `static-site-generator-webpack-plugin` to generate a static site for the single-page react app I'm working on.

The existing app uses react-dom's render function to render my app component into a div in my index.html file:

**index.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return <p>Hola!Yeah </p>;
  }
}

render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>React.js using NPM, Babel6 and Webpack</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app" />
    <script src="public/bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**webpack.config.json**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var StaticSiteGeneratorPlugin = require('static-site-generator-webpack-plugin')
var data = require('./data')

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/public');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/app');

var config = {
  entry: APP_DIR + '/index.jsx',
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  // Existing Code ....
  module : {
    loaders : [
      {
        test : /\.jsx?/,
        include : APP_DIR,
        loader : 'babel'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new StaticSiteGeneratorPlugin('bundle.js', data.routes, data)
  ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

But when I try to run webpack, I get this error:

```
ERROR in ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

based on some other tutorials, it looks like I should be able to render this way:

```
ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(App)
```

But this only renders the component, without the rest of the contents of my index.html.

What am I missing and how do I render my static site using webpack?